# How do I solve $\int\frac{xd(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

It might be an easy question, but I want to know how to solve an integration problem when the differential in the integration (sorry don't know its actual name) is not $\int d(x)$, like in the question above what if it's
$$\int d(x^2)$$
or
$$\int d(x^3 - 1)$$

Also, does this way of solving problems have a name or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this is a [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral)?

Comment: See the $$\int x\frac{d\boxed{1-x^2}}{\boxed{1-x^2}}$$

Answer (score 4):

In one variable, the differential of $f$ is defined as $\text{d}f=f'(x)\text{d}x$; hence $\text{d}(1-x^2)=-2x\text{d}x$.

So the integral you need to evaluate is
$$\int \frac{-2x^2}{1-x^2}\text{d}x$$

In particular, if you have $\int (\text{d}f)$ then it is $\int(\text{d}f)=f(x)+c$ with $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this into a form you are more familiar with by using the fact that:
$$df=\frac{df}{dx}dx$$
in this case:
$$d(1-x^2)=\frac{d(1-x^2)}{dx}dx=-2xdx$$

---

An alternative to this would be to say:
$$y=1-x^2$$
$$\frac{xd(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}=\frac{\pm\sqrt{1-y}\,dy}{y}$$
where the sign would depend on the use, however as you can see the first option is much easier

---

One thing to be careful of is the limits, since they will likely be related to the value of the function being integrated wrt e.g $f$ rather than the values for $x$

Answer (score 0):

See the $$\int x\frac{d\boxed{1-x^2}}{\boxed{1-x^2}}$$

Since $$\frac d{dx} (1-x^2)=\frac{d(1-x^2)}{dx}=-2x\implies d(1-x^2)=-2x dx$$

Therefore $$\int x\frac{d(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}= \int x\frac{-2x dx}{1-x^2} =2\int \frac{x^2}{x^2-1}dx$$

You can also try integration by parts:

$$\int u\,dv+\int v\,du=uv\mathop \implies^{ v=1-x^2, u=\frac{x}{1-x^2}}\int \frac{x}{1-x^2}d(1-x^2)= \frac{x}{1-x^2} (1-x^2)-\int(1-x^2)d\left(\frac{x}{1-x^2}\right)$$

Now use the Fundamental theorem of Calculus and use the differential:

$$x-\int d\left(\frac{x}{1-x^2} \right)-\int x^2d\left(\frac{x}{1-x^2}\right)=x+\frac{x}{x^2-1}-\int x^2d\left(\frac{x}{1-x^2}\right)= x+\frac{x}{x^2-1}-\int x^2\frac{x^2+1}{(x^2-1)^2}dx= x+\frac{x}{x^2-1}-\int \frac{x^4}{(x^2-1)^2}dx-\int \frac{x^2}{(x^2-1)^2}$$

Can you do one of the integrals from here?

Please correct me and give me feedback!